# Matching a value in subdocument array and matching array to _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of Users which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f2"
    },
    
    "name": "Billy Bob",
    "story": {
        "posts": [
           {"id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"}, 
           {"id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"}, 
           {"id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"}   
        ],
        "whoCanView": [{
            "$oid": "5ff891bd749ed24316272317"
        }, {
            "$oid": "5ffc89392056ad02272d10f3"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to get all users and their stories listed in an array which I call "contacts". The user currently querying the collection may only get results if their userId is in the "whoCanView" array.

This is what i have so far but doesn't seem to be working:

```
users.find({'story' : {
                        '$elementMatch' : {
                            '_id' : {'$in' : contacts},
                            ObjectID(userId) : {'$in' : 'story.whoCanView'}
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
ObjectID(userId) : {'$in' : 'story.whoCanView'}
```

Above line along with the usage of `$elemMatch` operator is wrong in your code. Try this query instead:

```js
let contacts = [
    ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f2"), 
    ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f3"),
    ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f4")
];

let userId = ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272317");

db.users.find(
    {
        "_id": { $in: contacts },
        "story.whoCanView": userId
    },
    {
        "strories": "$story.posts"
    }
);
```

Output when `userId` is `ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272317")`:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:1/7/2021, 2:50:15 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f2"),
    "strories" : [
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        },
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        },
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:1/7/2021, 2:50:15 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f3"),
    "strories" : [
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        },
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        },
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 createdAt:1/7/2021, 2:50:15 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f4"),
    "strories" : [
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        },
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        },
        {
            "id" : "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output when `userId` is `ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272318")`:

```js
[]
```

Test data in `users` collection:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f2"),
        "name": "Billy Bob",
        "story": {
            "posts": [
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" }
            ],
            "whoCanView": [
                ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272317"),
                ObjectId("5ffc89392056ad02272d10f3")
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f3"),
        "name": "Billy Bob",
        "story": {
            "posts": [
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" }
            ],
            "whoCanView": [
                ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272317"),
                ObjectId("5ffc89392056ad02272d10f3")
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f4"),
        "name": "Billy Bob",
        "story": {
            "posts": [
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" }
            ],            
            "whoCanView": [
                ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272317"),
                ObjectId("5ffc89392056ad02272d10f3")
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ff6298f2056ad02272d10f5"),
        "name": "Billy Bob",
        "story": {
            "posts": [
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" },
                { "id": "b4a12557-4dfa-47eb-9f27-7bbcad0f4c45" }
            ],            
            "whoCanView": [
                ObjectId("5ff891bd749ed24316272317"),
                ObjectId("5ffc89392056ad02272d10f3")
            ]
        }
    }
]
```